# Does changing the Windows 10 key affect some other software?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

if I change the Windows 10 Key on a PC with Microsoft Office or some other software. Can I get some trouble with licenses?

Do I have to reinstall something?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the software, office will not care but I can't say every program won't.